# Is it possible to "click" on things with python and selenium that doesnt have a selector when you open inspect

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to write a code that opens a website and performs different tasks. Some buttons don't have any selectors (i believe it is called), when I hover over them with my mouse using the inspect tool, nothing comes up. Is it possible to click on these buttons in any different way using python and selenium? For example by telling selenium to click on specific locations on the screen?

Comment: Related - [How to move the mouse in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167577/how-to-move-the-mouse-in-selenium).  Do you have an example site you can link to, for our testing?

Comment: Can you share a link to page with elements having no selectors? As mentioned by Bruce it is also possible to move to specific X,Y coordinates but in 99.9% it is possible to find a locator to any web elements.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.